# Philosophy of restorative justice?

Tags: justice

What are some good reading materials for: New Zealand's restorative justice? What is the philosophy behind it?

Comment: The section on [justice](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reconciliation/#RecJus) in the SEP article on reconciliation mentions restorative justice in its closing paragraph. For an applied example, see the University of Chicago's [research brief](https://educationlab.uchicago.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2023/09/UChicago-Restorative-Practices-2-pager-09.07.23.pdf) on the topic in connection with educational practices.